# How to convert xaxis to vertical placement

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using jquery flot charting tools. Please see this chart (make sure you choose a large date range)

http://bzreports.azurewebsites.net/#/discounts

Notice the xaxis is squished together? I would like to position the xaxis labels vertically instead of horizontally. I have not found a way to get this to work...

The options I am using are

```
var options = {
                xaxis: { ticks: _.map(data, function (item) { return [item.Id - 1, item.Discount]; }) },
                yaxis: { tickFormatter: function(val, axis) { return val.formatMoney(2); } }
            };
```

Comment: Have a look at this - [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204191/rotate-flot-tick-labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the problem in the link you provided, even with big data.

But have you tries giving the labels angle? like in here http://jsfiddle.net/manishsp2008/vNSD8/

```
xaxis: {
            labelAngle: 45}
```

Hope it helps!