# CSS Cross-browser Text Rotation

Tags: html, css, rotation

I am having problems getting text rotation to work in both Chrome and IE (11.0). In IE the texts rotates 180 and 360 degrees instead of 90 and 270.

This is the CSS-style (among others) I have tested:

```
.rot90 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -o-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;

    border: 0px solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;

    padding-bottom: 5px;

    writing-mode: tb-rl;
}

.rot270 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(270deg);
    transform:rotate(270deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -o-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;

    border: 0px solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;

    padding-bottom: 5px;

    writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

I need the transform origin to be at: 0px 0px.

Here is a jsfiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/wonc4px9/2/

Another jsfiddle using the http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html

- https://jsfiddle.net/wonc4px9/5/

**UPDATE**

Here is a working solution based on the marked answer, it was the writing-mode that messed things up: https://jsfiddle.net/wonc4px9/6/

```
.rot90 {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, M12=-1.00000000, M21=1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, M12=-1.00000000, M21=1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand');
    -moz-transform:  matrix(0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1.00000000, 0.00000000, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform:  matrix(0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1.00000000, 0.00000000, 0, 0);
    -o-transform:  matrix(0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1.00000000, 0.00000000, 0, 0);

    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -o-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;

    border: 0px solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;

    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.rot270 {

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=-0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=-0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand');
    -moz-transform:  matrix(-0.00000000, -1.00000000, 1.00000000, -0.00000000, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform:  matrix(-0.00000000, -1.00000000, 1.00000000, -0.00000000, 0, 0);
    -o-transform:  matrix(-0.00000000, -1.00000000, 1.00000000, -0.00000000, 0, 0);

    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -o-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;

    border: 0px solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;

    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you only stating a single value for the `transform-origin`? Doesn't it require two?

Comment: @Paulie_D Hmm.. not sure why I only have one value, I suppose i can fix that, still I am not sure it can impact on the rotation.

Comment: Try this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051030/rotating-text-with-css-and-ie

Comment: @lunaks What do you mean I should test? Something in the question or something in any of the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this website to generate a CSS rule for IE.[Matrix Calculator](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html)

In the answer part it's explained how to use it and why you need it.

It will look like this:

```
.rot90 {
-ms-filter:"The rule you get from the website"
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform:rotate(90deg);
transform:rotate(90deg);

-webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
-moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
-ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
-o-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
transform-origin: 0px 0px;

border: 0px solid;
white-space: nowrap;
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;

padding-bottom: 5px;

writing-mode: tb-rl;}
```

Comment: Can't get it to work, here is fiddle (new styles is rot90b and rot270b): https://jsfiddle.net/wonc4px9/5/

Comment: Finally I got it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/wonc4px9/6/ (it was the writing-mode: tb-rl; that messed it up).